# Set value of a string without setting it to str type?

Tags: python, string, setvalue

I'm looking for a way to set a string's value without changing the type of the string.

```
class testStr(str):
    myattr = ""

# this works fine.
t = testStr("testing")
t.myattr = "Yay!"
print "String value is: '" + t + "' and its attr is set to '" + t.myattr + "'"

# obviously once this is done the type of t goes back to str
# and I lose the value of .myattr
t = "whatever"
```

If possible I would like myattr to maintain it's value while the string is set to a new value. It doesn't need to work like t = "whatever" but I don't want to manually copy over the values of myattr and more if I put more variables into the testStr class.

**EDIT:** Here is the solution I ended up coming up with. It satisfies all of my needs, I was hoping for something a little more elegant but I'm happy with this none the less:

```
class config:
    class ConfigItem(str):
        def __init__(self, value):
            super( str, self ).__init__()
            self.var1 = "defaultv1"
            self.var2 = "defaultv2"

    def __init__(self):
        self.configTree = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if ( self.configTree.has_key(key) ): 
            return self.configTree[key]
        return ""

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if ( value.__class__.__name__ == "ConfigItem" ):
            self.configTree[key] = value
            return

        if ( value.__class__.__name__ == "str" ):
            item = None
            if ( self.configTree.has_key(key) ): 
                item = self.configTree[key]
                new_item = self.ConfigItem(value)
                for attr in item.__dict__:
                    new_item.__setattr__(attr, item.__getattribute__(attr))
                self.configTree[key] = new_item
            else: 
                item = self.ConfigItem(value)
                self.configTree[key] = item

# test it out
cfg = config()
cfg["test_config_item"] = "it didn't work."

cfg["test_config_item"].var1 = "it worked!"
cfg["test_config_item"] = "it worked!"
print cfg["test_config_item"]
print cfg["test_config_item"].var1
```

This allows a configuration setting to be used as a string, however it does still contain the additional information if it was needed.

Comment: Python variables aren't variables in the sense of C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `t = "whatever"` doesn't "change the value contained by `t`", but rather it rebinds `t` to a different object. If you want to change `t` then you must mutate it instead via an attribute, either by assigning to an attribute or by calling a method.

Comment: I'm prepared to use a method to set the value of the string. I just didn't want to do 'newt.myattr = oldt.myattr' to move over each variables value because then I will have to update the function to do that for every attribute I add to the class. I was hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (which you've figured out) is that t is being assigned to a new object of type str, which doesn't have myattr.

I think the simplest way to do this would be to simply create a class that doesn't inherit from str, but contains a string member as well as 'myattr'

Comment: I guess what I was really hoping for was that the str class contained an internal function to change the value or a variable that held it's value ( I was hoping for __ value __ or something )

Comment: If you want an object to have a string value then define the `__str__()` and/or `__unicode__()` methods.

Comment: @python5000 - The actual underlying character buffer isn't exposed, see http://svn.pythonmac.org/python24/python24-fat/Include/unicodeobject.h if you're interested @Ignacio - I think he wants to set it, not have a string value

Comment: Python strings are immutable, so you're out of luck. I have a similar class that attaches a tuple to a string, but I never needed to replace the string. The only thing that keeps biting me is that writing `t = "test" + strtuple("test2", 1, 2)` results in a plain `str` because the `str.__add__` operator drops the tuple. `t = strtuple("test", 1, 2) + "test2"` does work, though.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this approach. It seems to provide the functionality you're looking for.

```
class testStr(object):
    def __init__(self, string, myattr = ""):
        self.string = string
        self.myattr = myattr
```

Running the same test cases as you showed.

```
>>> from testStr import testStr
>>> t = testStr('testing')
>>> t.string
'testing'
>>> t.myattr = 'Yay!'
>>> t.myattr
'Yay!'
>>> t.string = 'whatever'
>>> t.string
'whatever'
>>> t.myattr
'Yay!'
```

Or, if you really want to inherit from str (but this is really less pythonic and also doesn't solve your problem):

```
class testStr(str):
    def __init__(self, string, myattr = ""):
        super(testStr, self).__init__(string)
        self.myattr = myattr
```

Comment: Yeah thats how this started out. I had exactly what you described however now my goal in life is to create a version where you can still print t and get "yay!" and still access .myattr even if I need to create a t.setValue("whatever") function.

Comment: @python5000 You mean print t and get 'testing'?  Why do you need to do that?  What's wrong with setting t.string, t.myattr and extending as needed?  You can always create t.setValue('whatever') so that it modifies self.string and leaves myattr alone.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using a tuple or list?

```
>>> s = [ ["the string", 15], ["second string", 12] ]
>>> print s
[['the string', 15], ['second string', 12]]

>>> s[0][1] = 8;
>>> print s
[['the string', 8], ['second string', 12]]

>>> print s[0]
['the string', 8]

>>> print s[1]
['second string', 12]
```